# Getting file path of imported module

Tags: python

How can I get the file path of a module imported in python. I am using Linux (if it matters).

Eg: if I am in my home dir and import a module, it should return back the full path of my home directory.

Answer (score 83):

Modules and packages have a `__file__` attribute that has its path information. If the module was imported relative to current working directory, you'll probably want to get its absolute path.

```
import os.path
import my_module

print(os.path.abspath(my_module.__file__))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: I think you could add how to obtain the plain folder name with `os.path.dirname(my_module.__file__)` like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003468/3734059

Comment: In my case the code in this answer didn't return anything, but this worked instead `os.path.abspath(my_module)`. The reason for that is I was in a weird situation where a directory had been given the same name of a commonly known module, and this caused the import to import the dir content instead (which didn't even contain python source files).

Answer (score 13):

I've been using this:

```
import inspect
import os
class DummyClass: pass
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(DummyClass))
```

(Edit: This is a "where am I" function - it returns the directory containing the current module. I'm not quite sure if that's what you want).

Answer (score 8):

This will give you the directory the module is in:

```
import foo
os.path.dirname(foo.__file__)
```

Answer (score 8):

I could be late here, some of the modules would throw `AttributeError` when using `__file__` attribute to find the path. In those case one can use `__path__` to get the path of the module.

```
>>> import some_module
>>> somemodule.__path__
['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/somemodule']
```

Answer (score 6):

To find the load path of modules already loaded:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from 'c:\Python26\lib\os.pyc'>
```

Comment: Or, simply put, `>>> os`. You're relying on `str()` representation of the module.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this method, which applies to both non-built-in and built-in modules:

```
def showModulePath(module):
    if (hasattr(module, '__name__') is False):
        print ('Error: ' + str(module) + ' is not a module object.')
        return None
    moduleName = module.__name__
    modulePath = None
    if imp.is_builtin(moduleName):
        modulePath = sys.modules[moduleName];
    else:
        modulePath = inspect.getsourcefile(module)
        modulePath = '<module \'' + moduleName + '\' from \'' + modulePath + 'c\'>'
    print (modulePath)
    return modulePath
```

Example:

```
Utils.showModulePath(os)
Utils.showModulePath(cPickle)
```

Result:

```
<module 'os' from 'C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\os.pyc'>
<module 'cPickle' (built-in)>
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work, where did you get the `imp` variable you are using in `imp.is_builtin(moduleName):` ?

Comment: "import imp". In addition, "DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses"

Comment: Please don't do `if cond is False` but instead `if not cond`. The keyword `is` is to verify the `id()` of objects, not truth.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> help('xxx')

For example

```
>>> help(semanage)
Help on module semanage:

NAME
    semanage

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/semanage.py
```