# How to get path of a python module ( not sys.executable )

Tags: python, path, pyqt, qwebkit

I need to get Path for PyQt library in python program. Program is run as a script from another application, therefore my

```
sys.executable = 'D:/program files/visum/exe/visum115.exe
```

and I need my actual python path (and path for PyQt library module)

```
Path = C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins
```

im trying with

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
```

but I'm not sure if it can be robust.

Regards!

PS. I need it to be able to plug plugins:

```
qApp.addLibaryPath('C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins')
```

Comment: Check here maybe it can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693608/find-path-of-module-without-importing-in-python/4693681#4693681

Comment: get standard library path, and list of its modules: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6464112/611007

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can try to load the module and after check for it's **__*file*__** attribute to get the path of the .pyc file.

for example like this:

```
import MODULE, os
path = os.path.dirname(MODULE.__file__)
```

Regards,
HTH!

Comment: this will not work with namespace packages, u will get: `AttributeError: module 'MODULE' has no attribute '__file__'`

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
 ['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper.github-0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycharm-debug.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Fom-0.9.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.6.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Numeric',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

Comment: but how to find python path in this tuple?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```
import PyQt

PyQt.__file__
```