# put a module file on a remote server using fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am writing a fabric file that which will take a dataset, send it to a server, run an analysis script on it, and retrieve the results.  If I hardcode the location of my script, `process_script`, I am all good. However, I would like to include the script as a file in a module and would therefore like to be able to access that file without hardcoding the location. Can I do it using the import system? I'm not sure. Here's a working version of what I'd like to do:

```
#data, script
datafile       = 'data.txt' 
process_script = 'process.py'

#simple function    
def upload_and_run():
    newdir = remote_dir + '/process_temp'
    put(datafile, newdir)
    put(process_script, newdir)
    with cd(newdir):
        run('python2.6 process.py {0}'.format(datafile))
    get(newdir,'%(path)s')

#pseudocode of how I'd like to access the process_script
process_script = from module import script
put(process_script, newdir)
```

any suggestions are appreciated,
thanks,
zach cp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729583/getting-file-path-of-imported-module) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path), I can access the module path using the `.__file__` attribute of the module. The script is then hardcoded with that path.

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(my_module.__file__)
process_script = path+ 'process.py'
put(process_script)
```