# Python 3.5 - Looking at source code - Where can I find genericpath module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at some source code in Python and see that it is importing the genericpath module.  Where can I find this module?

```
import genericpath
from genericpath import *
```

Searching for genericpath is turning up nothing...

Comment: Are you saying the above code fails on your machine? Show the stacktrace, please.

Comment: No it works fine. I just want to find and take a look at the generic path module

Comment: A good start would be to google the name of the module.

Comment: It's the first hit on Google. Also, see @Rogalski's answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting file path of imported module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729583/getting-file-path-of-imported-module)

Answer (score 9):

To check where module resides you may use `__file__` attribute.

```
>>> import genericpath
>>> genericpath.__file__
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\genericpath.pyc'
```

`genericpath` contains common implementation for `os.path` modules (`ntpath`, `posixpath`). Normally, you should never use any of these names explicitly, `os.path` will dispatch all requests to correct underlying library.